# Update EMM agent cert

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

Need some help, ime currently running the EMM v2 with 2000 android devices registered.

I have recently updated the cert and would like to know if this will break the agent. if it does how can i push the new bks file to the devices?

regards

Answer (score 0):

There can be issues if you have changed the cert. So you should manually push the new agent with new BKS file to all the devices.

Also, you can host the agent in the publisher and push it from the old server. But, at the time the agent gets updated in the device, it should run with the new server.